# How to pin terminal tabs in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: shell, intellij-idea, terminal

Is there a way to save terminal tabs amount, names and other settings in order for them to be automatically opened in IDEA after project opened?

May be some API to open it programatically via shell? Or plugin?

It is convenient for me to have multiple terminal tabs for web projects I'm working at, like `build`, `start`, `karma`, `git`, `npm` etc. But it is very annoying that i have to reopen them manually every time I open a project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not implemented at the moment, please vote for this request:

- [IDEA-117946](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117946) Save terminal tabs between sessions